# Contact form not sending to email

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contacts

Ok so my contact form was working fine when I first coded it into my website but now after a few months it has just stopped sending emails through to my address. I'm not sure if this is a problem with the code or with my email? Here is my current mail form...

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" value="form" >
                        <p>Name:</p><br /><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="25" /><br /><br />
                        <p>Email address:</p><br /><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="50" /><br /><br />
                        <p>Message:</p><br /><textarea name="contact_text" rows="6" cols="30" maxlength="1000" ></textarea><br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
                 </form>

                  <?php

                    if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['contact_text'])) {
                        $name = $_POST['name']; 
                        $email = $_POST['email'];
                        $text = $_POST['contact_text'];

                        if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($text)) {

                            if(strlen($name)>25 || strlen($email)>50 || strlen($text)>1000) {
                                echo 'Sorry, max length for some field has been exceeded.';
                            } else {

                                $to = 'my.email.address@gmail.com';
                                $subject = 'Contact form submitted';
                                $body = $text."\n".$name;
                                $headers = 'From: '.$email;

                                if (@mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
                                    echo '<h5>Thanks for the message, I will be in touch soon.</h5>';
                                } else {
                                    echo'<h4>Sorry an error occured, please try again later.</h4>'; 
                                }
                            }

                        }

                         else {
                            echo '<h4>All fields are required.</h4>';   
                        }


                    }


                   ?>
```

Comment: First thing it to remove the `@` from mail so you don't suppress any errors.

Comment: look for your emails in "SPAM" section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this mail header :

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
     'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
     'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: Actually ignore that last comment. This is working fine now. Thanks for your help!!!